# Other way for mouseOver a div

Tags: javascript, html

I made a div in the middle of screen that when the pointer enters the div a alert comes on screen.is there any other way for it?(not mouseOver,mouse Enter and hover things)

```
<body> 
<script>
function myBox(){
document.addEventListener('mouseover',function msg(){  alert("You r in the box")  })
}
</script>


<div onMouseOver="myBox()" id="box"> </div>  
</body>
```

By the way my code is OK and works i just need it to be done with other way not mouseOver and hover...

Comment: Hm... why? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Doodlebunch my code works i need it to be done with other way not mouseOver and hover...

Comment: Yes, and wanted to know what for? I can't imagine where this should be neccessary. But as far as I know there is no other method, beside of CSS and 'mousemove'.

Comment: @Doodlebunch i think there must be any other way for it..

Comment: Yes, but why? You dont like mouseover? What's about mousemove, mouseenter, mouseleave?

Comment: @Hereblur no not these things

Comment: @MelodyHajian, no, there's not such another way...you have to name things by its name and that's how you do things in the HTML/JS/CSS world, that's how you detect mouse-related events...

Comment: BTW, Are you sure it's working? It will alert when hover the box for first time, and next time it's alert no matter where the mouse is on the page. Correct?

Comment: @Melody Hajian You so you can use my solution.

Comment: I'm very curious as to why a different solution is needed at all. What's wrong with using mouse events or the `:hover` pseudo-class in CSS?

Comment: My teacher told me not to...

Comment: @MelodyHajian I'm really curious and I'm dying to know how your teacher'd do it without javascript event listeners or css pseudo classes

Comment: @Leo its a web development class and our teacher said to us not to use those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CSS Only**
>   **HTML**

```
<a>Hover over me!</a>
<div>Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/q8ap4pve/)

> **Javascript**

```
function isOutside(evt, parent) {
  var elem = evt.relatedTarget || evt.toElement || evt.fromElement

  while ( elem && elem !== parent) {
    elem = elem.parentNode;
  }

  if ( elem !== parent) {
    return true
  }
}

var parent = document.getElementById('parent')

parent.onmouseover = parent.onmouseout = function(e) {
  e = e || event

  if (isOutside(e, this)) {
    parent.nextSibling.nodeValue = new Date() + ' ' + e.type 
  } 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding:10px;border: 1px solid blue" id="parent">
 <p>Move the mouse in and outside of here. The blue box parent has <i>many</i> other <b>elements</b> inside.</p>
 <p>They do not generate extra `mouseover/mouseout` events.</p>
</div>
event
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/6bkvw807/)

Comment: how on earth this is NOT using a mouse-related event? Did you even bother reading the question and comments?

Comment: onmouseout, onmouseover, onmouse++, OP doesn't like them :p

Comment: You should use artificial intelligence. ``:)``

Answer (score 1):

You could use css **:hover** and **display: none;**
but css isnt able to make an alert frame, so it could only change style of some element

Comment: i said i don't wanna use hover and mouseOver...

Comment: Unfortunatelly I dont know about another solution :(